# target a button inserted by ajax with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hello i'm inserting this image with a button by ajax when visitor upload an image

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 1) {
    imageThump += '<img src="' + data[i].path + '" />';
    imageThump += '<button id="edit-details" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit Details</button>';
}
$('#uploaded-images-thumb').append(imageThump);
```

i want to target the button with javascript but it keeps failing ???

```
$('#edit-details').on('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to deal with dynamic event (aka live event). As the button injected into DOM after DOM load.

```
$('body').on('click', '#edit-details', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

NOTE: instead of `body`, should bind to its closest non-dynamic parent element.
If your `#uploaded-images-thumb` is non-dynamic then better to bind against it. like:

```
$('#uploaded-images-thumb').on('click', '#edit-details', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

For more detail check [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to [delegate the event](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), because when you inserted your event handlers, the element was not present:

```
$("body").on('click', '#edit-details', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

So we have selected `body`, which is a static tag and delegate the events inside them. Also, as a side-note, it is better to bind the event to the closest static parent and not the absolute parent, which is the `document` or the `body`.

In your example, it could be like:

```
$("#uploaded-images-thumb").on('click', '#edit-details', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Comment: it's better to bind event to closest parent element

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what was mentioned above is the answer. Essentially the element doesn't possess the same events (click) as the existing DOM elements, so when it's dynamically generated you don't have access to the needed events for the new element.

To expand on what the other posters have mentioned, Here is a small example of the structural idea.

```
<div id="element-wrapper">
    <button class="my-btn">Existing Button (has event)</button>
    <button class="my-btn">Existing Button (has event)</button>
    <button class="my-btn">Just Dynamically Added to DOM!!!</button>
</div>
```

This code below will work for all the buttons except the last one:

```
$('.my-btn').click(function() {
   alert('Clicked!');
});
```

This code below will work for ALL buttons (since '#element-wrapper' is not dynamic):

```
$('#element-wrapper').on('click', '.my-btn', function() {
   alert('Clicked!');
});
```

Comment: Yes the alert had a single quotation in the word, it was just an example. Fixed to remove the quotation problem.